# Inconstantly behaviour with UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning

Tags: ios, animation, uicollectionview, transition

I am doing a custom animation with `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` that works in this way: in a `collectionView` the user taps on a cell (a photo) and it grows fedding in until it reaches a certain frame in another controller. When the user taps on the close button in this last controller, the transition does the way back (from the last controller to the `collectionView` cell).

The first step works properly, while the second step it works not always properly. Sometimes it goes back to the right frame of the collection view and sometimes not, it deviates somewhere else.

Here below I put the code and in between some print to understand the behaviour of the frames:

```
import UIKit

class AccessPlanTransition : NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

 var presenting = false
 var index: NSIndexPath?

func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

if presenting {
  if let fromControllerList = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey) as? PlansListViewController,
    let toControllerHome = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey) as? HomeTableViewController,
    let container = transitionContext.containerView()

  {
    let duration = transitionDuration(transitionContext)

    let index = (fromControllerList.collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems()!.first)!

      if let cell = fromControllerList.collectionView(fromControllerList.collectionView!, cellForItemAtIndexPath: index) as? PlanInListCollectionViewCell {

        let cellImageViewSnapShot = cell.image.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(true)
        cellImageViewSnapShot.frame = container.convertRect(cell.image.frame, fromView: cell.image.superview)
        print("presenting cellImageViewSnapShot cell.image.frame \(cell.image.frame) cell.image.superview  \(cell.image.superview)")

        cell.image.hidden = true
        print("presenting cellImageViewSnapShot.frame \(cellImageViewSnapShot.frame)")

        toControllerHome.view.frame = transitionContext.finalFrameForViewController(toControllerHome)
        print("presenting toControllerHome.view.frame \(toControllerHome.view.frame)")
        toControllerHome.view.alpha = 0.0
        toControllerHome.travelImage.hidden = true

        container.addSubview(toControllerHome.view)
        container.addSubview(cellImageViewSnapShot)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: {
          toControllerHome.view.alpha = 1.0
          let frame = container.convertRect(toControllerHome.travelImage.frame, fromView: toControllerHome.view)
          print("presenting frame  \(frame)")
          print("presenting = container.convertRect toControllerHome.travelImage.frame \(toControllerHome.travelImage.frame) toControllerHome.view  \(toControllerHome.view)")
          cellImageViewSnapShot.frame = frame
          print("presenting cellImageViewSnapShot.frame \(cellImageViewSnapShot.frame)")
          }, completion: { finished in
            toControllerHome.travelImage.hidden = false
            cell.image.hidden = false
            cellImageViewSnapShot.removeFromSuperview()

            transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled())
        })
    }
  }
} else {
  if let fromControllerHome = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey) as? HomeTableViewController,
    let toControllerList = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey) as? PlansListViewController,
    let container = transitionContext.containerView()
  {
    let duration = transitionDuration(transitionContext)

    let imageSnopshot = fromControllerHome.travelImage.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(false)

    if let index = fromControllerHome.index {

    if let cell = toControllerList.collectionView(toControllerList.collectionView!, cellForItemAtIndexPath: index) as? PlanInListCollectionViewCell {

      cell.image.hidden = true

      toControllerList.view.frame = transitionContext.finalFrameForViewController(toControllerList)
      print("BACK toControllerList.view.frame \(toControllerList.view.frame)")

      imageSnopshot.frame = fromControllerHome.travelImage.frame
      print("BACK imageSnopshot.frame \(imageSnopshot.frame)")

      container.insertSubview(toControllerList.view, belowSubview: fromControllerHome.view)
      container.addSubview(imageSnopshot)

      UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations:  {
        fromControllerHome.view.alpha = 0.0
        print(index.row)
        imageSnopshot.frame = container.convertRect(cell.image.frame, fromView: cell.image.superview)
        print("BACK imageSnopshot.frame \(imageSnopshot.frame)")
        print("BACK container.convertRect cell.image.frame \(cell.image.frame) fromView: cell.image.superview \(cell.image.superview)")
        }, completion: { finished in
          imageSnopshot.removeFromSuperview()
          fromControllerHome.travelImage.hidden = false
          cell.image.hidden = false

          transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled())
      })
      }
    }
  }
}
 }

func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> NSTimeInterval {
return 0.5
}

}
```

Here the result of the console. I made several taps on the same collectionView cell placed in the same place, and every time the console result were the same for good an bad results:

GOOD WORKING

```
presenting cellImageViewSnapShot cell.image.frame (0.0, 0.0, 250.0, 400.0) cell.image.superview  Optional(<_UISnapshotWindow: 0x7fe910771000; frame = (1125 0; 375 667); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fe91076e290>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x7fe910761530>>)
**presenting cellImageViewSnapShot.frame (1125.0, 0.0, 250.0, 400.0)**
presenting toControllerHome.view.frame (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0)
presenting frame  (0.0, 0.0, 600.0, 470.0)
presenting = container.convertRect toControllerHome.travelImage.frame (0.0, 0.0, 600.0, 470.0) toControllerHome.view  <UITableView: 0x7fe91203a600; frame = (0 0; 375 667); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; tintColor = UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 1 1 1; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fe9106ae3c0>; animations = { opacity=<CABasicAnimation: 0x7fe912861510>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fe9105ea920>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {375, 13093}>
presenting cellImageViewSnapShot.frame (0.0, 0.0, 600.0, 470.0)
BACK toControllerList.view.frame (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0)
BACK imageSnopshot.frame (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 470.0)
**BACK imageSnopshot.frame (61.0, 144.0, 250.0, 400.0)**
BACK container.convertRect cell.image.frame (0.0, 0.0, 250.0, 400.0) fromView: cell.image.superview Optional(<UIView: 0x7fe9104b9920; frame = (0 0; 250 400); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fe910608300>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fe9104b7d90>>)
```

BAD WORKING

```
presenting cellImageViewSnapShot cell.image.frame (0.0, 0.0, 250.0, 400.0) cell.image.superview  Optional(<_UISnapshotWindow: 0x7fe9107ab970; frame = (1125 0; 375 667); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fe912932150>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x7fe910784a90>>)
**presenting cellImageViewSnapShot.frame (1125.0, 0.0, 250.0, 400.0)**
presenting toControllerHome.view.frame (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0)
presenting frame  (0.0, 0.0, 600.0, 470.0)
presenting = container.convertRect toControllerHome.travelImage.frame (0.0, 0.0, 600.0, 470.0) toControllerHome.view  <UITableView: 0x7fe9108bf400; frame = (0 0; 375 667); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; tintColor = UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 1 1 1; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fe912892220>; animations = { opacity=<CABasicAnimation: 0x7fe9107adff0>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fe912827d90>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {375, 13093}>
presenting cellImageViewSnapShot.frame (0.0, 0.0, 600.0, 470.0)
BACK toControllerList.view.frame (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0)
BACK imageSnopshot.frame (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 470.0)
**BACK imageSnopshot.frame (65.0, 34.0, 250.0, 400.0)**
BACK container.convertRect cell.image.frame (0.0, 0.0, 250.0, 400.0) fromView: cell.image.superview Optional(<UIView: 0x7fe912958590; frame = (0 0; 250 400); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fe910797f90>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fe9129322a0>>)
```

As we can see, the lines marked by ** are the one that deviate the right frame.

Do you have any reason why it behaves in that way?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `[view layoutifneeded]` (this would be that view whose alpha value you are changing) everywhere after alpha value is changed.

Hope this helps you! And if not then please let me know, I have done this type of transition.

This is my transition code snippet

```
UIViewController<DataSource> *fromVC = (UIViewController<DataSource> *) [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
UIViewController<DataSource> *toVC   = (UIViewController<DataSource> *) [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

UIView *containerView = [transitionContext containerView];

UIView *fromView = [fromVC sharedView];
UIView *toView = [toVC sharedView];

// Take Snapshot of fomView=
UIView *snapshotView = [fromView snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO];
snapshotView.frame = [containerView convertRect:fromView.frame fromView:fromView.superview];
fromView.hidden = YES;

// Setup the initial view states
toVC.view.frame = [transitionContext finalFrameForViewController:toVC];

if (self.presenting) {
    toVC.view.alpha = 0;
    [toVC.view layoutIfNeeded];
    toVC.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [containerView addSubview:toVC.view];
}else{
    [containerView insertSubview:toVC.view belowSubview:fromVC.view];
}
toView.hidden = YES;
[containerView addSubview:snapshotView];


[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{

    if(self.presenting){
        toVC.view.alpha = 1.0; // Fade in
    }else{
        fromVC.view.alpha = 0.0; // Fade out
    }
    // Move the SnapshotView
    snapshotView.frame = [containerView convertRect:toView.frame fromView:toView.superview];
    toVC.view.center = fromVC.view.center;
    [toVC.view layoutIfNeeded];

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    // Clean up
    toView.hidden = NO;
    fromView.hidden = NO;
    [snapshotView removeFromSuperview];

    // Declare that we've finished
    [transitionContext completeTransition:!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled];

}];
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Hello aaskash, thank your your reply. I tried to put  `toControllerHome.view.layoutIfNeeded()` and              `fromControllerHome.view.layoutIfNeeded()` after alpha value is changed as you said but unfortunately it doesn't solved the problem. Do I need to give you some more piece of info? Thanks

Comment: May i know which modalpresentationstyle you are using?

Comment: I am actually using a Push segue

Comment: I have edited my answer with code snippet please check it out.